# Need Help Filtering A LINQ Query Using An Entity Framework Navigation Property

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework

I need help filtering a LINQ query on an Entity Framework (EF) navigation
property. The tables were created first (not code-first).

For this problem, let's use the characters from The Office.

Suppose I have the following tables and columns:

```
Offices
    Id
    Name
    Location

Employees
    Id
    Name

EmployeeTypes
    Id
    Description

Employees_EmployeeTypes
    Id
    EmployeeId
    EmployeeTypeId
```

The tables have the following data:

```
Offices
    1   North Branch    PA
    2   South Branch    FL
    3   East Branch     NY

Employees
    1   Jim
    2   Pam
    3   Oscar
    4   Dwight
    5   Michael
    6   Angela
    7   Kevin
    8   Stanley

EmployeeTypes
    1   Manager
    2   Salesman
    3   Assistant
    4   Receptionist
    5   Accountant

Employees_EmployeeTypes
    1   1   2
    2   2   4
    3   3   5
    4   4   2
    5   5   1
    6   6   5
    7   7   5
    8   8   2
```

These tables are brought into EF using the "Update Model From Database"
functionality in Visual Studio.

All entities are named exactly like the table names and the entity sets are
pluralized.

```
Entity Name     Entity Set Name
Office          Offices
Employee        Employees
EmployeeType    EmployeeTypes
```

The Employees_EmployeeTypes table is a junction table (many-to-many), will
translate into a navigation property in EF and is named "EmployeeTypes". Here is
an example of its usage:

```
var employeeTypes = dbContext.Employees.Find(1).EmployeeTypes;
```

Now that we have the setup, let's get to the question. Using LINQ, how can I
select all employees who are a saleman using the navigation property
"EmployeeTypes"? In SQL it would look like this:

```
select e.Id, e.Name
from Employees e
join Employees_EmployeeTypes e_et on e_et.EmployeeId = e.Id
join EmployeeTypes et on et.Id = e_et.EmployeeTypeId
where et.Id = 2
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this fairly easily with the [`Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx) and [`Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx) methods:

```
var results = dbContext.Employees.Where(e => e.EmployeeTypes.Any(et => et.Id == 2));
```

Or if you prefer query syntax:

```
var results =
    from e in dbContext.Employees
    where e.EmployeeTypes.Any(et => et.Id == 2)
    select e;
```